# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte при установке PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как исправить данную ошибку?

```
ks.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vk6t05m_\PyQt5-sip\pip-wheel-metadata\PyQt5_sip.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vk6t05m_\PyQt5-sip\pip-wheel-metadata\PyQt5_sip.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vk6t05m_\PyQt5-sip\pip-wheel-metadata\PyQt5_sip.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vk6t05m_\PyQt5-sip\pip-wheel-metadata\PyQt5_sip.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vk6t05m_\PyQt5-sip\pip-wheel-metadata\PyQt5_sip.dist-info'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\pyQT5_app1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\pyQT5_app1\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_me
tadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpw0fvg4ba" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Данил\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vk6t
05m_\PyQt5-sip
```

Comment: Давайте прочитаем ошибку и узнаем, что проблема с кодировкой. Либо при чтении указать кодировку, либо поменять кодировку файла на utf-8.

Comment: ошибку скопируйте полностью. самое интересное на строчку выше. ошибку вставляйте текстом

Comment: eri, добавил код.

Comment: переменную PYTHONVERBOSE установи и запусти ещё раз.